# Is there any word for someone who makes many enemies?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe a historical person as someone who makes lots of enemies. His name: Alexander Hamilton. I don't want to insult him, just state the facts.

Is there any word for someone who makes many enemies?

Comment: That being said, you might want to flesh this out a little with some research and context....and as you are asking for a single word, a sentence with a blank to insert the desire word would help a lot.

Comment: So I want to describe a historical person as someone who makes lots of enemies. His name: Alexander Hamilton. I don't want to insult him, just state the facts.

Comment: Ah...that is an excellent example, and would certainly  help, but you should edit to include that in the Q.

Comment: ***Pugnacious*** and its many synonyms refer to the practice of being hostile. But I don't know that there is a single word which means that a person is inclined to make enemies - which is probably something that can be done without being pugnacious or aggressive.

Comment: Unfortunately, "honest" is all too often the driving characteristic.

Comment: @HotLicks By that, do you mean "tactless"?

Comment: 'Controversial'?

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking maybe *antagonist(ic)*, but it seems like that doesn't quite fit. Maybe *ill-disposed*?

Comment: I've no doubt the most well-disposed, or saintly person makes enemies, perhaps by virtue of their saintliness. This is really a question about human relationships. And if the OP wants a sensible answer they will have to articulate more clearly what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

You may be searching for "adversarial".

Comment: You could improve the answer by adding a dictionary definition for your chosen word.

Answer (score 0):

Such a word will be hard to find, I think it is better to just form a sentence that states that he had a multitude of enemies due to <<*insert reason*>>. There are many words to describe his possible nature though: antipathic, antagonistic, antithetical, odious, etc.

Comment: Welcome to the site please take the tour https://english.stackexchange.com/tour and then read our help centre post about how to write a good answer: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer